# Is there an open-source heat exchanger library written in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there an open-source heat exchanger library written in Modelica which covers different types of heat exchangers? Like on this web page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_exchanger

Comment: Did you check https://modelica.org/libraries?

Comment: The ModelicaStandardLibrary has a quite powerful Thermal and Media library. That should suffice for  most purposes.

Comment: I have checked the modelica.org/libraries, there is only a commercial library from Modelon(Heat exchanger library), as for the MSL, it seems not quite accurate when dealing with 2-phase flow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your previous posts and your Wikipedia link I assume that you need heat exchanger models for power plant simulation.

The one in MSL (`Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger`) is a generic, discretized model, not calculating heat transfer/pressure drop from plate or tube/shell geometry or condensation/evaporation as can be found in various norms and textbooks. However, you can extend the model to include e.g. number of tube tiers/rows etc. and you can add your own two-phase heat transfer models based on `Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.BaseClasses.HeatTransfer.PartialFlowHeatTransfer`. But this requires a bit of work from your side.

Otherwise, there are a number of freely available options — among others:

1. ClaRa library by XRG/TLK Thermo ([www.claralib.com](https://www.claralib.com/)) is extremely capable and aimed for power plant simulation. Note that the version you can find on GitHub is **not** the official library maintained by the original authors.
2. ThermoPower by Francesco Casella ([github.com/casella/ThermoPower](https://github.com/casella/ThermoPower)) has been around for many years and its models are well proven and documented.
3. Modelica Buildings Library ([github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings)) has a number of different heat exchanger models that are all *very easy* to use but are without geometrical information. This library uses MSL fluid connectors.

Comment: You could also add TRANSFORM library to the list as it is clearly the bestest of the best ;) (it's the library I created so definitely super biased on that recommendation): TRANSFORM https://github.com/ORNL-Modelica/TRANSFORM-Library

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the ThermoSysPro library is not in the list? Just asking.

Comment: I have no experience with ThermoSysPro. Also, all its connectors are incompatible with those from MSL and my impression of the library is that its development is quite de-coupled from the general work in the Modelica library comunity.

Comment: @Tomillo such valid questions, as yours here, is one of the reasons why questions asking for external resources are actually off-topic in SO; see #4 in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and detailed explanation therein.